# Terraform import aws_appautoscaling_policy resource error with / in policy_name

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to import an AWS resource of type aws_appautoscaling_policy from an old terraform state to a new one. This is the aws_appautoscaling_policy id.

```
ecs/service/sandbox/myservice/ecs:service:DesiredCount/ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization:service/sandbox/myservice
```

its id has 4 components:

- namespace: `ecs`
- resource_id: `service/sandbox/myservice`
- scalable_dimension: `ecs:service:DesiredCount`
- policy_name: `ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization:service/sandbox/myservice`

The command that I used to import the resource is:

```
terraform import aws_appautoscaling_policy.ecs_targettrackingcpu ecs/service/sandbox1/myservice/ecs:service:DesiredCount/ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization:service/sandbox1/myservice
```

But I got this error

```
Error: reading Application Auto Scaling Policy (myservice): describing scaling policies: ValidationException: 1 validation error detected: Value 'sandbox' at 'scalableDimension' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy enum value set: [cassandra:table:ReadCapacityUnits, cassandra:table:WriteCapacityUnits, dynamodb:index:ReadCapacityUnits, dynamodb:index:WriteCapacityUnits, appstream:fleet:DesiredCapacity, comprehend:document-classifier-endpoint:DesiredInferenceUnits, ec2:spot-fleet-request:TargetCapacity, rds:cluster:ReadReplicaCount, elasticache:replication-group:Replicas, dynamodb:table:WriteCapacityUnits, kafka:broker-storage:VolumeSize, ecs:service:DesiredCount, sagemaker:variant:DesiredInstanceCount, comprehend:entity-recognizer-endpoint:DesiredInferenceUnits, dynamodb:table:ReadCapacityUnits, lambda:function:ProvisionedConcurrency, custom-resource:ResourceType:Property, neptune:cluster:ReadReplicaCount, elasticache:replication-group:NodeGroups, elasticmapreduce:instancegroup:InstanceCount]
```

I think its because in the policy name it has 2 `/` while it shouldn't. Thus, terraform can not parse the scalable_dimension correctly.

###### Note:

- terraform version: 1.3.7
- terraform aws provider version: 4.52.0

Anyone has encountered this kind of issue before and how to fix it? Please let me know.
Thank you.

I tried to add escape character from the import command like this but it didnt seem to work:

```
terraform import aws_appautoscaling_policy.ecs_targettrackingcpu ecs/service\/sandbox1\/myservice/ecs:service:DesiredCount/ECSServiceAverageCPUUtilization:service\/sandbox1\/myservice
```

Comment: Please do not use screenshots for errors, but provide them as properly formatted text.